# Classifying color in dark surroundings

Tags: algorithm, color-theory

In a program I am working on, I am trying to classify colors based on their RGB values as red, orange, yellow, green, blue, or white. I am classifying them by comparing the given RGB values to a constant "ideal" value for each color and finding the minimum euclidean distance in a three dimensional space. However, I am having trouble when the color I am analyzing comes from a dark image as the current program has difficulty differentiating between orange, yellow, and red within dark images. How should I fix or work around this issue?

Comment: I suggest you put your imagines into e.g. the gimp and try auto-exposure / auto-levels / auto-whitebalance and similar adjustments to see if any of them produce an image for which your program works.  If so, do a bit of reading about what that adjustment does to the image, and either apply a similar adjustment using an imagine processing library or write it yourself.

Comment: Please consider upvoting/following the StackExchange Color Theory site: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110687/color-theory

Answer (score 0):

The environment is always going to cause problems. Say if the only light source is red you won't be able to tell apart gray, green or blue.

If your situation is not that complex you could try to adjust the image. Almost all image processing software/libraries have some functions to that end. Probably the best solution would be to have some calibration components in the scene like a white ball that you know what color it should be and can help you adjust the image and make the color identification easier.

Comment: I already compare to known values in the scene so I will try the image adjustment, thank you very much for your answer.